# Responsive HTML page

Tags: html, responsive-design

Looking at the source code of any HTML page, what is the decisive factor by which we can say that this page is responsive.
Is the presence of proper 'media query' enough to say that the page will be responsive?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Responsive Design, is so that the page can adjust its content to accommodate a new window/screen size. Usually this is done by Media Queries as you have stated in the question, and this is probably by far the most widely used solution. However there are a few other things you can do...
A fluid grid - content coded specifically with relative sizing such as percentages.
There is the kinda old-school solution of using several websites for each device, such as mobile, tablet, desktop and you just determine which one you should redirect the user to in accordance with their device and screen dimensions.
There are probably more other ways for responsive design.

So to answer, it probably is down to personal understanding of responsive design to which you decide whether a website is responsive design or not. The web industry leans more towards the use of media queries and fluid grids. Remember, responsive design however it is done, adapts to the end-user's screen size or device.